# Number of ways to put 10 people into 2 rooms but the rooms cannot be differentiated

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

I know how to do this question if the rooms can be differentiated, which has multiple posts in Math Exchange. Thise is done by knowing that each of the 10 person can pick either room 1 or 2, and hence there is $2^{10}$ ways. However, how to do this if the room cannot be differentiated? I am confused because in the case for example when there are $10$ people in one room and $0$ in the other, there are only two ways to put the people (all in room 1 or all in room 2) but when there are $5$ in each room, there are much more ways to put them than $2$ ways.

A follow up question would be, what is the probability of each room having a) 5 persons each and b) what is the probability of each room having 3 and 7 persons respectively, where the rooms cannot be differentiated.

(intial guess):

a) $\frac{\frac{10!}{(5!)^2}}{2!}$

b) $\frac{10!(2)}{3!7!}$

Comment: [Hint](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Comment: Denote the room that has person 1 as room 1, and then put 9 people into the 2 rooms.

Comment: Each distribution where the rooms can't be distinguished corresponds to two distributions where the rooms can be distinguished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you differentiate the rooms, the answer to the question in the title is $2^{10}$. If you don’t differentiate the rooms, you should divide by $2$ since every distribution is counted $2$ times now. So the answer is $2^9$.

You can also use the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) since they are used to determine number of partitions of distinguishable objects into indistinguishable groups. The number of ways to split into $2$ non-empty groups is S($10,2$). There is also the (only) case when one room is empty. The answer would be S($10,2$)+S($10,1$)=$512$.

About the follow-up question. Are you assuming that all the partitions are equally probable? If yes, then the answer for (a) is indeed $\frac{\binom{10}{5}/2}{2^9}$.

There is no need to multiply by $2$ in (b). You just don’t divide by $2$ as you did in (a). You split into $2$ groups one of which is $3$ people, it can’t be changed with the group of $7$. There are ways $\binom{10}{3}$ to choose a group of three, and these choices can’t be repeated. So the answer is $\frac{\binom{10}{3}}{2^9}$.

—————

It is always useful to consider a smaller example to understand. Let us split $4$ people (we call them a, b, c, d) into $2$ indistinguishable rooms. There are $8$ ways to do so:

abcd|-

abc|d $\quad$ abd|c $\quad$ acd|b $\quad$ bcd|a

ab|cd $\quad$ ac|bd $\quad$ ad|bc

Note that $8=2^{4-1}$ holds. The number of ways to partition into groups of two is $3$ which is indeed equal to $\binom{4}{2}/2$. The number of ways to split into groups of one and three is $4$ which is equal to $\binom{4}{1}$.